# Link styles are not working

Tags: html, css, hover, hyperlink

I'm trying to style my links and I have used this code for that:

```
.navtext {
    position:absolute;
    top:130px;
    right:50px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:20px;
    z-index:3;
}

a.navtext:link {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a.navtext:hover {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

a.navtext:visited {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

And here is my html:

```
<div class="navtext">
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a href="about.php">About</a>
    <a href="school.php">School</a>
    <a href="workshop">Workshop</a>
    <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
</div>
```

But they are staying as the default (Link: blue, underlined. No Hover. Visited: Purple, underlined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a.navtext` selects an `<a>` tag with the class "navtext".

You have no such `<a>` tag. Your `<a>` tags have no classes.

Try something like `.navtext a` instead. This selects an `<a>` tag within an element with the class "navtext".

Answer (score 1):

```
.navtext a {
    position:absolute;
    top:130px;
    right:50px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:20px;
    z-index:3;
}

.navtext a:link {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.navtext a:hover {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.navtext a:visited {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
.navtext a:link      {   color:#ffffff;
                    text-decoration:none;
                }

.navtext a:hover     {   color:#ffffff;
                    text-decoration:underline;
                }

.navtext a:visited   {   color:#ffffff;
                    text-decoration:none;
                }
```